# To big PixMap? QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I tried to do:

```
double mm1 = 1200/2.54;

    double zoom=mm1;
    double szer=99;
    double wys=210;

    QPixmap pixmap(szer*zoom,wys*zoom);
    QPainter painter;
    QPen DarkGray(Qt::gray,1);
```

and become error:
 QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2

Is my pixmap to big? What to do?

Comment: Your painter is not associated to any paint device. You probably want `QPainter painter(&pixmap)`

Comment: Where do you call `painter.begin(...);`?

Comment: ...  `QPainter painter;
    QPen DarkGray(Qt::gray,1);

    painter.begin(&pixmap);`

Comment: i become error if size  x>20000,y>20000 i.e.:  `pixmap(20000,20000);` , if i choose i.e.: `pixmap(100,100);` it is ok!

Comment: i found something like size limitation  (32767x32767 pixels)... but what i i neef something bigger? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080052/qimage-qpixmap-size-limitations

Comment: You should start from the beginning. Explain what are you trying to achieve. Maybe there is a better solution than painting on a `QPixmap`.

Comment: i would like to draw some on QPixmap (QPainter) and than print it all;  my pritner works in 1200 dpi, so  my idea:   `float mm1 = 1200 px/2.54 ;//(1 inch)`; then i create my QPixmap (99*mm1,210*mm1)  ... draw something on it and after all - print;  `QPainter p (&printer); p.drawPixmap(0,0,px.width(),px.height());`

Comment: Why don't you draw directly on the printer? Why draw on the pixmap first and then on the printer?

Comment: because of previev on QLabel... i create small previev on-line...