# How to make QPixmap display the svg？

Tags: python, svg, pyqt

I have a big svg(70000 * 2000) and I want to display it completely.
I Used QPixmap and I found it was incomplete.
This is my code:

```py
self.img = QPixmap('test.svg')
self.scaled_img = self.img

def paintEvent(self, e):
    painter = QPainter()
    painter.begin(self)
    self.draw_img(painter)
    painter.end()

def draw_img(self, painter):
    painter.drawPixmap(self.point, self.scaled_img)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [QPainter documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#limitations):

> If you are using coordinates with Qt's raster-based paint engine, it is important to note that, while coordinates greater than +/- 2<sup>15</sup> can be used, any painting performed with coordinates outside this range is not guaranteed to be shown; the drawing may be clipped.

This seems to be a limitation valid for QImage and QPixmap too, as explained in the answer to [QImage/QPixmap size limitations?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080898), which means that the image will only be rendered up to 32767x32767.

You may want to try using [QSvgRenderer.render(painter, rect)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#render-1) in order to scale it, or [`setViewBox()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#viewBox-prop) and then the basic [`render()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html#render) to show portions of it.