# QImage/QPixmap + .xpm file size limitations?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

In my application, I am trying to load multiple `.xpm` images.

```
    #include "Images/Destroyed_xpm.h"
//...
    QPixmap(Destroyed_xpm).toImage()
```

When trying to load a 35 * 35 pixels object (above) everything works fine (app compiles, runs. Corretly initialised `QImage` obj), but when trying to load an image

```
#include "Images/MainWindowBackGround_xpm.h"
//...
QPixmap(MainWindowBackGround_xpm).toImage()
```

with 892 * 419 pixels the program produces a huge number of errors during compilation:

```
3 !3 Ne L9 '3 q9 m~ t= t= o= t= m= o= t= o= o= w9 ;. Oe r= Pe Qe 1~ Re Se Te Ue Ue Ve We Ve Xe Ye Ze `e  f .f .f +f @f 23 #f .f $f %f &f *f 53 A9 =f -f ;f >f *f 7  ,f 'f 'f )f !f F:-1: ошибка: ~f {f ]f ^f ). /f :3 Qe (f _f 03 I9 :f <f [f }f [f p~ d3 |f 1f }f q9 2f Ne 3f 4f c3 5f 6f Q9 7f 8f 9f 0f af R9 bf cf df ef ff gf hf if jf kf lf mf nf :} of pf qf F3 rf sf Y] tf uf vf :} wf @0 ,0 %- A| xf yf zf Af Bf ,0 *{ Cf Df Ef Ff Gf Hf If |0 Jf Kf m+ Kf Lf [- Mf Nf Of b< Pf Qf 70 Rf Sf Tf 90 Sf Pf 70 _{ Uf Vf Wf Xf Yf Zf U{ `f  g .g +g @g #g $g %g &g *g =g 4{ -g ;g >g ,g 'g )g !g ~g {g ]g ^g /g (g _g :g <g [g }g |g 1g 2g 3g 4g 5g 6g 7g 8g ^{ 9g 0g ag bg cg dg eg fg gg hg ig 8; jg kg lg Kf mg 10 1< mg ng og pg qg rg sg tg ug vg wg xg yg zg  ] <[ Ag *g Bg Cg Dg 1; !] Eg W4 Fg Gg Hg Ig Jg Gg O{ Kg Lg Mg Ng Og Pg Qg Rg Sg Tg Y5 Ug Vg R- Wg Xg Yg Zg `g  h .h +h @h #h $h %h &h *h =h -h ;h >h ,h 'h )h >9 !h ~h {h ]h ^h /h (h _h :h <h [h Cf }h |h 1h 2h 3h 4h 5h 6h 7h 8h 9h 0h ah bh ch dh eh fh gh hh ih jh kh lh mh nh oh lg ph qh rh sh th uh 6) *b vh wh xh yh zh Ah Bh Ch Dh Eh Fh Gh Hh Ih Jh Kh Lh Mh Nh Oh Ph Qh Rh Sh Th Uh Vh Wh Xh Yh Zh `h  i .i +i @i #i $i %i &i *i =i -i ;i >i ,i f} E- 'i )i !i ~i {i ]i ^i /i (i _i :i Kb <i [i }i |i 1i 2i 3i 4i 5i 6i 7i 8i 9i w| m' .6 0i ai xb bi #6 Hc L^ ci di ei M6 X> fi gi Qb hi ii Ub x6 Vb ji ki E6 ^/ =| li *| mi #$ a,  c ]/ ;| k( Z6 ni oi F6 // '| F6 )| ^/ {/ F6 pi a/ qi ri si ti ui C# vi wi xi {b yi zi Ai 'c Bi Ci t7 Di B$ Ei Fi e$ D, 6, I, .$ I, k, Gi Hi {$ A( Ii Ji Ki :c Li Mi Ni (_ b& Oi Pi .7 Qi h$ o| Ri Si Ti Ui Vi Wi Xi Yi Zi `i  j .j +j @j #j $j %j &j *j =j $8 2i -j ;j >j ,j 'j )j !j ~j {j ]j ^j /j (j _j :j <j [j }j |j 1j 2j 3j 4j 5j [8 6j 7j 8j 9j 0j aj T^ bj cj dj ej fj gj hj h' ij jj kj lj mj nj _, h] oj pj md qj rj sj tj uj vj wj xj +d yj zj Aj `| 0, Bj o( Cj Dj Ej Fj Gj Hj Ij V* z2 Jj Kj Lj Mj Nj Oj Pj Qj Rj Sj Tj Uj Vj Wj Xj Yj Zj `j  k .k +k @k #k $k %k &k *k =k -k ;k >k ,k 'k )k !k ~k {k ]k ^k /k (k _k :k <k [k 9# }k F> |k a8 1k =, 2k 3k c' )_ '_ 4k 5k )_ 9/ lj 6k &1 7k 8k 9k 0k ak bk x2 ck dk ek ]> A) ek fk .! Ld +! q8 gk ~2 i_ e_ Od ]2 7_ U) 8_ hk ik jk kk lk mk nk ok lk Vd pk Xd $> qk rk sk tk ]> ]> uk uk vk Gd ,2 wk xk yk zk Ak Bk Ck Ck Dk Ek Fk Gk Hk Ik Ck Jk s_ >e Kk Lk Mk Nk Ok Pk Qk :e Rk Sk Tk Uk Vk Wk Xk Yk .9 Zk `k  l .l +l @l @b @b #l $l %l !9 &: &l &: *l =l F2 be -l ;l k* >l H! j* ^9 ,l ]9 M* ]9 'l ve ve J2 y! )l ~d !l 9e v( ~l {l ]l z* ^l T2 /l oe F* (l :9 :9 :9 qe Fj _l :l <l [l E! #: *) D! D! *) }l *) |l 1l K2 %: ",


102850 | "   .  +  @  #  $  %  &  &  %  *  =  -  ;  >  ,  '  )  !  ~  {  ]  ^  /  (  _  :-1: ошибка: <  [  <  }  |  [  1  2  2  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  a  b  c  5  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  f  k  d  l  5  m  m  n  k  o  n  g  2  <  1  1  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  1  w  x  e  y  z  A  A  A  B  C  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  H  H  H  K  L  M  N  O  N  P  Q  R  S  T  U  T  V  W  X  Y  Z  `   . l  .. +. @. #. $. %. %. &. *. =. -. -. ;. >. ,. '. ). *. !. ~. {. .. ]. ^. /. (. _. :. <. [. }. |. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9. 0. a. b. c. d. e. f. f. g. g. h. i. j. k. j. l. m. n. o. p. q. p. r. s. t. u. v. w. x. y. y. z. A. B. B. C. D. E. F. G. H. I. J. K. L. M. N. O. P. Q. R. S. T. U. V. W. X. Y. Z. `.  + .+ ++ @+ #+ $+ %+ &+ *+ =+ *+ -+ ;+ >+ ,+ '+ )+ !+ ~+ {+ ]+ ^+ /+ (+ _+ :+ <+ [+ }+ |+ 1+ 2+ 3+ 4+ 5+ 6+ 7+ 8+ 9+ 0+ a+ b+ c+ d+ e+ f+ g+ h+ i+ j+ k+ l+ m+ n+ o+ p+ q+ r+ s+ t+ u+ v+ w+ x+ y+ z+ A+ B+ C+ D+ E+ F+ G+ H+ I+ J+ K+ L+ ;+ M+ N+ O+ P+ Q+ R+ S+ T+ U+ V+ W+ X+ Y+ Z+ `+  @ .@ +@ @@ #@ $@ %@ &@ *@ =@ -@ ;@ >@ ,@ '@ )@ !@ ~@ {@ ]@ ^@ /@ (@ _@ :@ <@ [@ }@ |@ 1@ 2@ 3@ 4@ 5@ 6@ 7@ 8@ 9@ 0@ a@ b@ c@ d@ e@ f@ g@ h@ i@ j@ k@ l@ m@ n@ o@ p@ q@ r@ s@ t@ u@ v@ w@ x@ y@ z@ A@ B@ C@ /  D@ E@ F@ G@ H@ I@ J@ K@ L@ M@ N@ O@ P@ Q@ R@ S@ T@ U@ V@ W@ X@ Y@ Z@ `@  # .# +# @# ## $# %# &# *# =# -# ;# ># ,# '# )# !# ~# {# ]# ^# /# (# _# :# <# [# }# |# 1# 2# 3# 4# 5# 6# 7# 8# 9# 0# a# b# c# d# d# e# f# g# h# i# j# 8# k# l# m# n# o# p# q# r# s# t# u# v# w# x# y# z# A# B# C# D# E# F# G# H# I# J# K# L# M# N# O# P# Q# R# S# T# U# V# W# X# Y# Z# `#  $ .$ +$ @$ #$ $$ %$ &$ *$ =$ -$ ;$ >$ ,$ '$ )$ !$ ~$ ~$ {$ ]$ ^$ /$ ($ _$ :$ <$ [$ }$ |$ 1$ 2$ 3$ 4$ 5$ 6$ ^$ 7$ 8$ 9$ 0$ a$ >$ b$ c$ d$ e$ .$ f$ g$ h$ i$  $ j$ k$ l$ m$ n$ o$ p$ q$ r$ s$ t$ u$ v$ w$ x$ y$ z$ A$ B$ C$ D$ E$ W# F$ G$ H$ I$ J$ K$ L$ M$ N$ O$ P$ Q$ R$ S$ T$ U$ V$ W$ X$ Y$ Z$ `$  % .% U# +% @% #% $% %% &% *% =% -% ;% >% ,% '% )% !% ~% {% ]% x# ^% /% (% _% :% <% [% }% |% 1% 2% 3% 4% 5% 6% 7% 8% 9% 0% a% b% c% d% e% f% g% h% i% j% k% l% m% n% o% p% q% r% k% s% t% u% v% w% x% y% z% A% B% C% D% E% F% G% H% I% J% K% L% M% N% O% P% Q% R% S% T% U% V% W% X% Y% Z% `%  & .& +& @& #& $& %& && *& =& -& ;& >& ,& '& )& !& ~& {& ]& ^& /& (& _& :& <& [& }& |& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7& 8& 9& 0& m% a& b& c& d& e& f& g& g& h& i& j& k& l& l& l& m& n& n& o& m& p& q& r& s& t& u& v& w& x& y& z& A& B& C& D& E& F& G& H& I& J& K& L& M& N& O& P& Q& R& S& T& U& V& W& X& Y& Z& `&  * .* +* @* #* $* %* &* ** =* +* -* ;* >* ,* '* )* !* '* ~* {* ]* ^* /* (* _* :* <* [* }* |* 1* 2* 3* Q% Q% 4* 5* 6* 7* 8* 9* 0* a* b* c* d* e* f* g* h* 8* i* j* i* k* l* m* n* m* o* p* q* r* q* s* t* u* v* w* x* y* x* y* z* A* B* C* D* E* F* G* H* I* J* i* K* k* k* k* k* L* j* k* M* M* N* ",

102858 | ".3 ze 29 29 we 49 Dr Er &} Fr Gr Hr Ir Jr Kr f9 :-1: ошибка: w  @. 93 Lr Mr Je <. &3 Nr Or Pr Qr Rr Sr Tr Or Ur Vr Wr Xr Wr kl Yr nl x~ :. nl L9 Zr `r  s .s +s Zr ^f ^f q9 )3 ^f o9 !3 )3 @s )3 )3 L9 #s o= o~ o~ o= B: c3 c3 t= o= $s 73 %s &s *s =s 1f -s ;s >s ,s 's )s !s ~s ~s 's 's {s ]s ]s Ve ^s ^s Ve /s Ve (s xl {s _s 's )s {s ~s :s :s <s J  4= 6= 6= [s }s |s |f rl 1s 2s '3 ;. Ql 3s 03 I9 4s 5s 6s 7s 8s 7s 9s 0s as bs cs ds es J9 J9 fs gs hs X: X: X: is js ks ls ms ns os 0f ps af qs rs ss ts us vs ws xs ys zs As Bs Cs Ds Es Fs Gs Hs Is Js Ks << Cf Ls Sn Ms Ns Os Ps Qs Rs Ss ^0 Ts Us Vs Ws Xs Ys `0 Zs Zs A4  4  4 `s Mf  t hm 3[ .t +t @t #t $t #t %t &t *t =t -t 90 ;t >t ,t 't )t Wf Im !t ~t {t ]t ,n ^t h0 5{ /t (t _t :t ,g <t [t }t |t 1t 2t 3t 4t 5t Pm 6t 7t 8t 9t 0t at bt ct dt et ft gt ht it jt kt lt mt nt ot pt qt l; rt st tt ut vt wt xt W5 60 yt C4 zt At Bt Ct Dt Et Ft Gt Ht It Jt Kt Lt Mt Kt Nt Ot Pt Qt Rt St Tt Ut Vt Wt Xt Yt Zt `t 2{  u .u 8{ +u @u 8- #u $u %u &u *u pn =u -u ;u >u ,u 'u )u !u ~u 2- {u ]u ^u /u (u v3 A= _u :u <u [u }u |u 1u 2u 3u 4u 5u 6u 7u 8u 9u 0u au Tf bu cu du eu fu gu hu iu ju ku lu mu nu ou pu ;j qu ru &e su tu Q, uu e$ vu wu xu hu $| yu zu Au F> )7 Bu Cu Du Eu Fu Gu Hu Z* Iu Ju Ku Lu Mu Nu Ou Pu Qu Ru Su Tu Uu Vu Wu Xu Yu Zu `u  v .v +v @v #v $v %v &v y1 *v =v }# -v ;v >v ,v 'v )v !v ~v {v ]v ^v {) /v (v _v :v O< <v [v m; }v |v 1v 2v 3v ^i 4v 5v 6v 7v 8v 9v 0v av bv cv *p dv e_ ev fv gv  p hv iv jv kv lv s^ -% po mv $p nv E> ov pv qv X> Rb rv sv tv uv vv wv xv yv ~| Gi zv `, Av =| 0, Bv b, 6, c/ .c Cv Dv ~| 5p Ev Fv :q 7) Gv ^c Hv Iv Jv Kv Lv Mv Nv Ov Pv Qv Rv )1 @c Sv nd X,  $ Tv Uv 6/ i, m, h, xv h, g, Vv Gi Wv Vb Xv e, Yv n) Zv `v  w .w +w @w #w bp $w %w &w *w =w -w ;w >w ,w 'w <e )w !w ~w {w ]w ^w /w (w _w :w <w [w }w |w 1w 2w 3w 4w 5w 6w 7w 8w 9w 0w aw bw cw dw ew ,k [) &u fw gw hw iw jw kw lw mw nw Ic ow pw qw rw sw tw uw ,  vw 9l ww xw yw zw Aw Bw Cw l, 8k Dw Ew Fw Gw Hw Iw Jw Kw yj Lw Mw J7 Nw Ow Pw Qw Rw Sw Tw Uw Vw Ww Xw -) =l Yw Zw `w  x .x +x @x #x $x %x &x Gw *x =x -x ;x >x ,x 'x )x !x ~x {x ]x 07 ^x /x (x _x :x <x [x }x |x 1x 2x 3x 4x 5x 6x 7x 8x 9x 0x ax bx cx !& =, k/ dx ex j% fx Nq 8( _c )( gx hx Ba ix jx kx n) lx 98 .7 mx C# nx C# m% [% ox px qx rx s8 y& [2 sx k& #2 U) tx }2 e_ @! ux vx I& gk P) Qd Jd y& wx Md G& xx yx zx Ax @r Bx Cx Dx Ex Fx Gx Hx Ix Jx Kx Lx ,r ]> n1 G6 Mx n8 Nx Ox Px Qx Rx _r Sx Tx Ux Ux )! (r N_ Vx Wx Xx Yx Q8 Zx `x  y .y +y @y #y Qk $y Rk #y %y &y *y =y -y P_ ;y  l 32 `k >y ,y r_ 'y )y !y ~y &: {y &l hr ir ]y ^y lr /y (y H! N2 j* ^9 _y ^9 ,l :y <y [y 'l -) }y )9 rr |y rr 1y 2y 3y 4y ]l y* (9 g1 !: P! D* 5y :9 :9 6y 7y 8y 9y 0y ay by v! U7 D! ~9 E! D! E! P2 D! [y -) cy ",
```

The top three lines of both files in the filesystem

```
/* XPM */
static char * Destroyed_xpm[] = {
"35 34 2 1",
```

,

```
/* XPM */
static char * MainWindowBackGround_xpm[] = {
"892 419 102846 3",
```

Fs shows: `1.4 kB` and `2.9 MB` size.

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080052/qimage-qpixmap-size-limitations) was noted that

> Both are limited to 32767x32767 pixels.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what does your 3rd snippet mean? Source code? Error message? It doesn't look like either or. If that is source code it is broken. (The trick with the XPM file format is that it has to look like C source code, to make it usable as such directly.) If it is an error message... There must be something essential missing.

Comment: A side note: XPM was intended for small icons (IMHO). It's capable to store larger images as well but it's size will explode then. Another image format might be more suitable e.g. PNG. Have a look at [The Qt Resource System](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). It allows to "bake" files into your binary and handle them like ordinary files concerning `QImage`-from-file-loading.